# How to use swift function that returns a value - in objective C?

Tags: swift, objective-c-blocks, ibm-watson, alchemyapi, bridging

I am using [IBM Watson APIs - Alchemy Data news](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk)

The problem is, I am using swift - objective C bridging and in between I am stuck with the function that returns a value. How do I use that value in my objective C code?

Here is my swift class

```
@objc class alchemyNews : NSObject {

func getNewsList() -> NewsResponse {

    let apiKey = "api-key"
    let alchemyDataNews = AlchemyDataNews(apiKey: apiKey)

    let start = "now-1d" // yesterday
    let end = "now" // today
    let query = [
        "q.enriched.url.title": "O[IBM^Apple]",
        "return": "enriched.url.title,enriched.url.entities.entity.text,enriched.url.entities.entity.type"
    ]
    let failure = { (error: NSError) in print(error) }

    alchemyDataNews.getNews(start, end: end, query: query, failure: failure) { news in
        print(news)

    }

    let response : NewsResponse = alchemyDataNews.getNews(start, end: end) { news in
        return news
    }

    return response
}
}
```

I want to have alchemyDataNews.getNews print value to be display. So I am calling this function in my Objective C class in this way.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AlchemyDataNews *getnews;

-(void)loadNews
{
   self.getnews = [[AlchemyDataNews alloc]init];
   [self.getnews getNewsList];

}
```

But what to do now? This will just call the function and not give me the response so that I can put it in array and display in tableview.

Comment: I'm most really sure about your Swift implementation... it seems to want to use a data on a synchronous way, which you collect via an asynchronous workflow; so I think you will need to rewrite your original function entirely to use a _completion closure_ instead of a _return_ value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is `getNewsList` returns an instance of `NewsResponse`, you should store it in a variable and then use it.

```
self.getnews = [[AlchemyDataNews alloc]init];
NewsResponse *newResponse = [self.getnews getNewsList];

// now you can use 'newResponse'
// ...
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: and the swift class is ok? Is there any mistake?

Comment: Yes, it should be

Answer (score 2):

The [`NewsResponse`](http://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/ios-sdk/services/AlchemyDataNewsV1/Structs/NewsResponse.html) type (and its primary property, [`NewsResult`](http://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/ios-sdk/services/AlchemyDataNewsV1/Structs/NewsResult.html)) is a `struct`. Unfortunately, Swift's `struct` types do not bridge to Objective-C. To use the Swift-to-Objective-C bridging, you will need to write Swift code to further process the `NewsResponse` type.

For example, you might choose the information from each `NewsResponse` that you're interested in and store those values in a Swift `Dictionary` (which bridges to an Objective-C `NSDictionary`). Alternatively, you could expose the table view to Swift and write Swift code to populate it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks you so much :)